# Ranging over golang map, inserting the new key

Tags: go

```
func hello() {
    myMap := make(map[int]bool)
    i := 0
    myMap[0] = false  
    for val, ok := myMap[i]; ok && !val; {
        fmt.Println("val", val)
        i--
    }
}
```

Why does this code run infinitely ? ideally it should once only once. can someone explain this ?

Comment: The init statement is only executed once. `ok` and `val`'s value never changes.

Comment: https://go.dev/ref/spec#For_clause

Answer (score 1):

**ok** and **val**'s are not update, this for update that values

```golang
for val, ok := myMap[i]; ok && !val; {
        fmt.Println("val", val)
        i--
        val, ok = myMap[i]
    }
```